# trigger jenkins job from bitbucket repository push

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I have installed jenkins on my azure vm.
I have installed the jenkins plugin "Generic Webhook Trigger"
I have created a freestyle build item :
 in the section "Build Triggers" I have check "Generic Webhook Trigger"
 in the section "Source Code Management", set my repository url to the repository to watch

When I open a browser and type the following url in the adress bar : http://JENKINSURL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke
A build is triggered on jenkins

But what I would like to do, is trigger a build not by typing this url in a browser adress bar but by pushing some code modifications on a repository, to do that I have add a webhook 
in the settings of my bitbucket repository :

the url is the same as before : http://JENKINSURL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke
the status is active
the checkbox skip certificate verification is checked
the triggers selected is "Repository push"

With all of that, when I do a push on the repository, a request is made to my jenkins server but not build is trigger and when I go to the request detail on bitbucket, I see that I get a 404 http status as response.

I don't understand what to add to trigger the jenkins build from a bitbucket code push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add a token in the generic webhook trigger settings. This token is added to you url in Bitbucket also.

Comment: Can you tell me what I have to update on the bitbucket settings and the jenkins settings?

Comment: for jenkins side: https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger scroll to "token"

Comment: the url which contain now a token section needs to be set on bitbucket server. Best description: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver068/managing-webhooks-in-bitbucket-server-981145446.html